# How to attach vinyl bracket to cement post?

Tags: fence

I have a vinyl fence post that was filled with cement. The vinyl fence panel brackets were screwed in before the cement was added so this wasn’t an issue,  But now a few brackets have broken off and I am having trouble replacing them. Every vinyl screw breaks when I try to go into the cement even when I pre-drill a hole. And the cement screws don’t seem to be holding.  Am I just not using the right screw, or is there a better way to attach plastic to cement?

Comment: How thick is the post?

Comment: around 8 inches

Comment: By vinyl screws, do you mean they are really made of vinyl, or are they just vinyl-coated?

Comment: They are metal screws that came with the brackets, very weak, but they work fine in one spot where there is no cement inside near the top.

Comment: There are several kinds of concrete screws. Which ones are you using and how are you installing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a self-tapping concrete screw, as long as the concrete is not brittle.  You need to pre-drill a pilot hole but after that nothing more than screwing the screw in.  The only problem is the screw size is probably a little bigger than you need.  I think 3/16 x 1-1/4" is the smallest made, but other manufacturers might make smaller.

[image: Self Tapping Concrete Screws]

Any questions click [here](http://www.confast.com/articles/tapcon-screw.aspx).

Comment: Think I'll try this and if not, I'll use the bolt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If feasible, drill all the way through the post and use nuts and bolts.  Or, use lead or plastic achors in your drilled holes in the concrete.  Or, use epoxy in the holes and clamp your bracket in place until the epoxy sets.

Comment: If they ever fall off again, I'll do this.